# Selenium evento click

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy comenzando con Selenium y estoy haciendo pruebas en una web, pero me encuentro con la siguiente estructura, y no consigo hacer click en el siguiente. Es un enlace dentro de una etiqueta li.

```
<li class="last">
     <a onclick="sendFormWithOptionsCU(event, 'https://www.xxx.com');" href="https://www.xxx.com">»</a>
</li>
```

Codigo en python

```
btnSiguiente=navegador.find_element_by_class_name('last')

print btnSiguiente

enlace=btnSiguiente.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

print enlace

btnSiguiente.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
```

Pero no ejecuta el botón siguiente. He probado también con el xpath, pero como cambia la web, no me lo detecta en siguiente ocasiones.

Answer (score 0):

como es una clase seria con un selector algo asi ...

```
WebElement enlace = navegador.findElement(By.cssSelector(".a"));
enlace.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías buscarlo también creando un xpath sería algo así, te lo paso en java ya pasalo a python, creo que no debe ser difícil.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath="//li[@class='last']//a[@href='https://www.xxx.com']");
```

Ya solo queda darle click

```
element.click();
```